# How to pass an InputStream via RMI

Tags: java, rmi, inputstream, fileinputstream

Consider these two functions:

`Function A` takes inputStream as parameter.

```
public void processStream(InputStream stream)
{
  //Do process routine
}
```

`Function B` loads a file content to pass it to `Function A` as `InputStream`.

```
pulic void loadFile()
{
 File file =new File("c:\\file.txt");
 //Pass file as InputStream
}
```

How can I pass file from `Function B` to `Function A` as InputStream without reading it on first hand?

I did something like this:

```
File file = new File("c:\\file.txt");
DataInputStream stream= new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
```

This generated the exception below:

```
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: java.io.DataInputStream
```

**EDIT:**

`loadFile()` is passing the InputStream as RMI response.

Comment: Your question is really 'how to pass an InputStream via RMI'? The answer is you can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work just fine

```
processStream(new FileInputStream(file));
```

You should only **not** attempt to serialize an `InputStream` instance by `ObjectOutputStream` like as

```
objectOutputStream.writeObject(inputStream);
```

which you're apparently doing in `processStream()` method. That's namely exactly what the exception is trying to tell you. How to solve it properly depends on the sole functional requirement which you omitted from the question.

---

**Update** as per the comment

> *I am passing the InputStream as an RMI response.*

There's the problem. You cannot pass non-serializable objects around as RMI response, let alone unread streams. You need to read the `InputStream` into a [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) the usual IO way and then use its `toByteArray()` to get a `byte[]` out of it and pass that instead. Something like:

```
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file); 
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];

for (int length = 0; (length = input.read(buffer)) > 0;) {
    output.write(buffer, 0, length);
}

byte[] bytes = output.toByteArray(); // Pass that instead to RMI response.
```

Be careful with large files though. Every byte of a `byte[]` eats one byte of JVM's memory.

Comment: `@BalusC` I am passing the InputStream as an RMI response.

Comment: I did a little research and found this library: http://openhms.sourceforge.net/rmiio/ which may allow you to stream your data over RMI (if it's too large to hold in memory).

Answer (score 1):

That exception seems to indicate that you are calling the `processStream` method on a remote object using something like RMI?  if that is the case, you will need to re-visit what you are doing.  sending streams of data over RMI is not an easy thing to do.  if you are *guaranteed* to be using small files, you could copy the file data to a `byte[]` and pass that to the remote method call.  if you need to process larger files, however, that will most likely cause memory issues on the client and/or server.  in that case, you should use something like [rmiio](http://openhms.sourceforge.net/rmiio/), which provides utilities for streaming data over RMI.

Comment: `@jtahlborn` yes loadFile() is passing the InputStream as an RMI response.

Comment: @jtahlborn what is the definition of "small" and "large" file in this context?

Comment: @quarks technically "small" is whatever fits in memory.  although a better definition would be whatever _reasonably_ fits in memory (i.e. still leaves room for the rest of the program to work well).

Answer (score 0):

You could just pass the `FileInputStream` ?

```
processStream(new FileInputStream(yourFile));
```

The reason you are getting the exception is because [DataInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) is intended to read primitive Java types